# Fastest non negative matrix factorization (NMF) solver in python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently using sklearn's ProjectedGradientNMF and nimfa's Lsnmf solvers to factor a very sparse matrix. ProjecteGradientNMF runs slower but converges to a closer solution while Lsnmf runs about twice as fast but converges to a further solution (frobenius norm distance measure).

I'm curious what the current fastest or closest solvers are available to the python community or is there a better option for a sparse matrix (the matrix is sparse, not scipy.sparse)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a benchmark here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4852 which is a pull request including the coordinate descent solver from mblondel https://gist.github.com/mblondel/09648344984565f9477a

What do you mean by sparse not scipy.sparse? Which library is it from?

Comment: I just wanted to comment that the matrix itself is sparse. I've done more research and came up with 2 additional great libraries. As they comment on in the scikit learn pull, there is an excellent package called Nimfa which contains many recent implementations. Also, Jingu Kim implements many of his solvers on his github page /kimjingu.

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.17 of [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-17) has a solver based on Coordinate Descent, which is considerably faster than the previous Projected Gradient.